# Selecting a user and show all records from different tables for that user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a view where you may search for a user `name` or `id` and once you click search, the view will show tabs with the users records from various tables. For example, I have a customer list and when searching a customer name, tabs will appear, one showing the customers address details from the `address` table, another tab will show their recent purchases from the `purchases` table, another will show their complaints from the `customer_complaints` table. Could someone advise me on the best way that I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Quickest way to do tabs is to use bootstrap where you can just show the intended table under the corresponding tab. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: @fufubrocat but will I be able to show the tables for a specific user? I don't want to display all records from all tables, just the selected user records per table

Comment: Of course you can. You can retrieve records for example, from your purchases table. Assuming you already have data in it and that your column name for identifying the buyer is named `buyer_id`, you can do a query like `Purchase::where('buyer_id', '=', $userIdHere)->get();`. This will show all the purchases on record made by the user with that id.

Comment: @fufubrocat do you perhaps have any resources or an examples of this? I am really confused and stuck

Comment: This should help you learn how to create and display data: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-crud-application-tutorial-for-beginnersexample.html